# Java, null point exception with split()

Tags: java, split

Im getting a nullpointerexcpetion when I run this. it allows me to enter all the input fields, but than throws the null pointer. Can someone explain to me why it is doing this. I think it has something to do with the split(). There are three classes, below. Any help would be great. Essentially i want to take the input, split it into an array, and call display the string at a specific index.

```
//Main Class
public class StarWars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInput input = new getInput();
        splitInput myInput = new splitInput();
        input.firstName();
        input.lastName();
        input.maidenName();
        input.cityName();

        System.out.println(myInput.splitFirstName());

    }
}

//second class
import java.util.Scanner;


public class getInput {

    public String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String maidenName;
    private String cityName;

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void firstName(){    
        System.out.printf("Enter your First Name:");
        firstName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void lastName(){
        System.out.printf("Enter your Last Name:");
        lastName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void maidenName(){
        System.out.printf("Enter your Mom's Maiden Name:");
        maidenName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getMaidenName(){
        return this.maidenName;
    }

    public void cityName(){
        System.out.printf("Enter your birth City:");
        cityName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getCityName(){
        return this.cityName;
    }
}

//Third Class
public class splitInput {
    public String splitFirstName(){
        getInput input = new getInput();
        String x = input.getFirstName();
        String[] splitValue = x.split("");
        String myValue = splitValue[2];
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: what line does it throw the exception at

Comment: `String x = input.getFirstName();`, here `x` is `null` because `firstName` has not been initialized (you declared a brand new instance of `getInput` just before). Then trying to split on it throws the NPE.

Comment: [This](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) java debugging tutorial might be of interest to you. It's lightweight, to say the least.

Comment: please post the exception stack trace.. just by looking into the stacktrace you can identify the issue

Comment: What is `splitFirstName()` supposed to do?  It seems to call `split` with an empty string as a parameter (not a space or other regexp), then it assumes there are at least 3 entries by accessing `splitValue[2]`.

Comment: Class names in Java should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those commenting who are curious, the Exception indeed happened on this line, because `x` was `null`.

```
  String[] splitValue = x.split("");
```

The problem is that you made all the calls to get data on the `myInput` object in `main`, but you did not pass it into `splitFirstName`. Instead, you created a completely new `input` object.

Change the method `splitFirstName` to take `input` as an argument.

```
//Third Class
public class splitInput {

    public String splitFirstName(getInput input){

        String x = input.getFirstName();

        System.out.println(x);
        String[] splitValue = x.split("");

        String myValue = splitValue[2];

        return myValue;

    }
}
```

Pass the argument in from main:

```
System.out.println(myInput.splitFirstName(input));
```

Note that your code as is, will print out the first third character of the first name. 
If that is not your intent, you should probably change it.

Also, the `Java` convention is to name classes with an uppercase first letter, and to use nouns rather than verbs to name classes.

Comment: Thanks so much Merlin. I really appreciate your help and tips. Just starting in Java. You are very helpful!

Comment: @Srmuhs, You are very welcome. I know it can be hard for beginners to ask questions here, but I'm glad you posted enough code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke this statement in main class

```
System.out.println(myInput.splitFirstName());
```

you are calling `splitFirstName()` method and within it you are creating a **new instance** `getInput input = new getInput();` and from the new instance you are trying to get its properties which are **Null**.. `String x = input.getFirstName();` 
here x value is null.

To solve this

Pass getInput object to splitFirstName method  to `System.out.println(myInput.splitFirstName(input));` and  change your method signature to `public String splitFirstName(getInput input){` and Comment the new instance statement

Below i have modified your code which is working::;

```
package com.test.punith;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    getInput input = new getInput();
    splitInput myInput = new splitInput();

    input.firstName();
    input.lastName();
    input.maidenName();
    input.cityName();

    System.out.println(myInput.splitFirstName(input));

}
```

}

class getInput {

```
public String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String maidenName;
private String cityName;

Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

public void firstName(){    
    System.out.printf("Enter your First Name:");
    firstName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();

}

public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}

public void lastName(){

    System.out.printf("Enter your Last Name:");
    lastName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
}

public String getLastName(){
    return this.lastName;
}

public void maidenName(){

    System.out.printf("Enter your Mom's Maiden Name:");
    maidenName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
}

public String getMaidenName(){
    return this.maidenName;
}

public void cityName(){

    System.out.printf("Enter your birth City:");
    cityName = user_input.next().trim().toLowerCase();
}

public String getCityName(){
    return this.cityName;
}
```

}

//Third Class
class splitInput {

```
public String splitFirstName(getInput input){

    //getInput input = new getInput();

    String x = input.getFirstName();

    String[] splitValue = x.split("");

    String myValue = splitValue[2];

    return myValue;

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through my mess Punith. I appreciate it!